# Apache start fails

Tags: apache, ssl

I am setting up a internal virtual host on Apache with a self signed certificate.  I have my VirtualHost config and when I try to start Apache, I get an error stating the cert if either missing or empty.  I have checked my persmissions and cert and everything looks proper so I'm not sure why i'm getting this error.  What is wrong with my config?

VirtualHost config:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName www1
  ServerAlias www1
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /var/certs/www-cert.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/certs/www-cert.key
</VirtualHost>
```

The error from apache:

```
[root@www1 scripts]# systemctl status httpd
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2016-12-17 16:13:50 CST; 44s ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)
           man:apachectl(8)
  Process: 10109 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 10107 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 10107 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Dec 17 16:13:50 www1 systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Dec 17 16:13:50 www1 httpd[10107]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 6 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/default.conf:
Dec 17 16:13:50 www1 httpd[10107]: SSLCertificateFile: file '/var/certs/www-cert.crt' does not exist or is empty
Dec 17 16:13:50 www1 systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 17 16:13:50 www1 kill[10109]: kill: cannot find process ""
Dec 17 16:13:50 www1 systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Dec 17 16:13:50 www1 systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Dec 17 16:13:50 www1 systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Dec 17 16:13:50 www1 systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
```

The cert does exist:

```
[root@www1 scripts]# ls -la /var/certs
total 12
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root   44 Dec 17 16:13 .
drwxr-xr-x. 22 root root 4096 Dec 17 14:57 ..
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root 1253 Dec 17 16:13 www-cert.crt
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root 1704 Dec 17 16:13 www-cert.key
```

The cert is valid:

```
[root@www1 scripts]# openssl x509 -text -noout -in /var/certs/www-cert.crt
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 17817470849210419499 (0xf7445f561b10892b)
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=CA, ST=Manitoba, OU=www1/emailAddress=root@localhost
        Validity
            Not Before: Dec 17 22:13:49 2016 GMT
            Not After : Dec 11 22:13:49 2021 GMT
        Subject: C=CA, ST=Manitoba, OU=www1/emailAddress=root@localhost
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:b2:76:fa:a8:8a:0d:ee:97:2f:5c:f8:7d:2a:48:
                    e9:f8:ce:c6:df:62:5f:23:e4:be:ea:c0:9c:25:09:
                    31:30:df:90:fc:6b:1b:58:62:98:29:aa:13:39:93:
                    bc:4d:d2:b8:7a:9f:e8:09:c1:e6:dc:1d:57:67:67:
                    33:61:6e:eb:a8:52:a6:77:70:19:ed:2a:58:5a:79:
                    35:ba:af:18:c2:2f:be:06:6a:8b:33:12:e7:63:03:
                    63:12:36:ed:ae:8e:c5:13:b5:2a:be:25:ac:dc:8a:
                    a5:dc:bc:86:49:27:29:7f:cd:5e:e1:ec:d9:a5:9f:
                    34:63:cc:7b:34:fa:2e:27:da:7b:90:a2:27:46:9b:
                    0b:e1:0a:68:a2:ed:df:1a:b6:48:ef:4f:c9:23:a8:
                    cf:7e:4c:da:ff:1f:80:52:fb:15:10:39:03:b5:d2:
                    0d:64:4b:df:9c:0f:41:9a:a0:d8:a1:c7:25:aa:19:
                    ee:c6:01:81:8b:be:7a:d8:c6:8c:cd:8f:13:51:68:
                    6d:78:00:72:76:d7:19:9b:d1:66:73:43:4b:30:9b:
                    de:96:29:81:80:40:31:39:43:e1:c4:2c:4a:c0:19:
                    4e:9b:d1:f5:e7:2b:d5:36:e3:eb:ef:31:e5:32:b1:
                    53:5b:f7:a5:c1:17:94:e9:ab:79:e2:02:be:c0:6f:
                    98:b1
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
                2C:E5:06:10:BB:24:32:27:7A:7F:50:00:A8:A5:D6:FC:86:5C:58:1F
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
                keyid:2C:E5:06:10:BB:24:32:27:7A:7F:50:00:A8:A5:D6:FC:86:5C:58:1F

            X509v3 Basic Constraints:
                CA:TRUE
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         05:69:cb:ee:4d:b5:3c:cb:c4:fb:2f:ac:26:b8:fd:db:bf:41:
         69:d0:a2:5b:cd:cc:04:53:f5:32:fc:7d:c9:fb:54:9d:d4:bf:
         41:02:09:0a:19:51:b1:69:bb:87:87:34:91:28:d4:1d:64:49:
         3e:38:27:ad:74:91:4a:e2:dc:85:4f:56:92:ad:fe:f1:9d:17:
         ca:e7:b2:2f:2f:89:62:fd:47:a0:0d:67:fb:6b:3b:8a:59:ae:
         73:03:97:72:c7:4c:d7:23:a3:b7:1f:ed:8a:bf:03:8a:00:40:
         1b:b4:02:d5:f6:73:45:4b:fd:1b:44:9d:9d:46:ca:c1:30:a0:
         53:5d:a3:2b:da:09:84:e6:97:9c:66:e5:a2:92:12:99:c5:03:
         7f:b7:f6:03:3d:d8:f3:ea:72:f4:ce:2b:73:dd:c6:72:e7:fb:
         55:6e:b5:44:11:52:56:ce:3d:0b:d8:40:cb:7e:ed:89:06:c6:
         ec:3a:0b:94:e7:54:ce:5e:d6:13:1f:3e:9f:35:47:9b:46:89:
         97:80:62:14:f7:40:3e:f6:bc:d9:16:7e:c3:51:27:eb:ab:db:
         80:d8:7e:ae:e5:a8:bb:09:28:73:ae:07:1f:78:79:b5:df:5f:
         60:85:c3:1e:93:29:95:4e:92:c2:96:e8:ec:a8:46:51:05:a3:
         eb:3d:96:f2
```

Comment: `restorecon -RvF /var/certs/` might help

Comment: and if needed add `chcon unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_config_t:s0 /var/certs/www-cert.crt`

Comment: Thanks for the response, but unfortunately these suggestions have not fixed the problem.

Comment: does `setenforce 0` help?

Comment: I set SELinux to disabled, restarted and that did solve the problem.  If you put your comments as a response, I will mark as answer.  You sent me in the right direction.